# Bencoded string length in java

Tags: java, bencoding

I am a bit confused with bencoding.

According to the specification when I bencode string I need to use the following format:

**length:string**

String **spam** becomes **4:spam**

My question: **4** is qty of symbols of bencoded string, or qty of utf-8 bytes?

For instance, if I am going to bencode a string **gâteau**

What number should be specified as a length of this string?

I think I have to specify **7**, and the final form should be **7:gâteau**

It is because symbol **â** took 2 bytes accoring to utf-8 encoding, and all the rest symbols in this string took 1 byte according to utf-8 encoding.

Also I heard that it is not recommended to store bencoded data in java String instance.

In other words, when I bencode a data block, I should store it as a byte array and should not convert it to java String value to avoid encoding issues.

Are my assumptions correct?

Comment: From http://stackoverflow.com/tags/bencoding/info: *A byte string (a sequence of bytes, not necessarily characters) is encoded as <length>:<contents>. [...] The specification does not deal
with encoding of characters outside the ASCII set*. What is unclear?

Comment: @JBNizet thank you. Please correct me if I am wrong. If I need to bencode a string with non-ascii characters, the `length` will show the qty of bytes, not characters. And for string `gâteau` the bencoded form will look like: `7:gâteau` as I described in my question. Am I right?

Comment: The specification, according to the text quoted in my comment, doesn't support non-ASCII characters. So you shouldn't be encoding `â` in the first place. But if you do, given that it says that it's a **byte** string, the length should be the number of bytes: 7. That's how I read it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[According to the specification](https://wiki.theory.org/BitTorrentSpecification#Bencoding), bencoded string is a sequence of bytes, and you have to specify qty of bytes for this sequence as its length.

And, from the specification: "*All character string values are UTF-8 encoded*".[image: specification]

And for your case with "gâteau" you should specify **7** as length, because character **â** takes 2 bytes.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation :)

Comment: I would like to clarify that *"All character string values are UTF-8 encoded"* is a specific restriction only on *character strings* in .torrent(Metainfo) files. It does **not** apply to *bencoded byte strings* in general, which can contain any arbitrary form of raw byte strings.